# How can I filter data between 2 dates in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I have a report which i want to display the data within 3 days, i.e. when a user runs the report it should display data as of yesterday, today and tomorrow.

```
Where [tasSched].[CurrReqstDate] Between *yesterday today and tomorrow*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server` you can use below query to get the data between yesterday and tomorrow.

```
WHERE [tasSched].[CurrReqstDate] between DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE()) 
                                     and DATEADD(DAY, +1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: @Ali please accept the answer (by clicking tick mark) if it helped you so that it will be useful for others